# How to use Class.forName(Myclass) where class is there in package

Tags: java

```
package com.serviceProvider;
public class Airtel implements Sim
{--}
----------------------
package com.mobile;
public class Mobile {

    public void insertSim(String simName) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{
        Class sim=Class.forName(?);
        Object ob=sim.newInstance();
        System.out.println(ob);

    }

}
```

How to configure Class.forName(?) there I need to load Airtel class which is there in `package com.serviceProvider`.

Comment: Class.forName("com.serviceProvider.Airtel"),  make sure that class is on the class path.. if it is not then you will get a ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: This question can be solved by consulting the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: i can handle Chris but how to load a class Class.forName(?)...

Comment: @AmritpalSingh please clarify, what do you mean by Class.forName(?) if it is not Class.forName("com.serviceProvider.Airtel")

Comment: @AmritpalSingh are you thinking that you want the class name to come in via the method arg?  thus.. 
 
Class.forName("com.serviceProvider."+simName)

Answer (score 1):

```
Class.forName("com.serviceProvider.Airtel");
```

but make sure your class is on classpath, otherwise you will get exception `ClassNotFoundException`